# Extract nested JSON data to Pandas Dataframe in python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to extract data out of an API JSON dataset. But I am failing to reach the nested data.

My dataset:

```
 data = {"Response":"Success",
 "Message":"",
 "HasWarning":"false",
 "Type":100,
 "RateLimit":{},
 "Data":{"Aggregated":"true",
         "TimeFrom":1571915400,
         "TimeTo":1572035700,
         "Data":[{"time":1571915400,
                  "high":6711.38,
                  "low":6701.93,
                  "open":6702.19,
                  "volumefrom":37.47,
                  "volumeto":251308.25,
                  "close":6703.24,
                  "conversionType":"direct",
                  "conversionSymbol":""},
                 {"time":1571916000,
                  "high":6705.19,
                  "low":6698.49,
                  "open":6703.24,
                  "volumefrom":50.1,
                  "volumeto":335895.53,
                  "close":6700.89,
                  "conversionType":"direct",
                  "conversionSymbol":""}]}}
```

And so on 200 times.

The part of my code:

```
api_r = requests.get(url).json()
df = pd.DataFrame(api_r["Data"])
```

I am trying to extract the data out of the array "data", but my dataframe returns a distorted view of all data before the array, I think because the name "data" is used for an earlier object as well. I have been trying and trying, as well `df = pd.DataFrame(api_r["Data"]["Data"])` but this didn't work.

Is somebody willing to help me with this issue?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you want the output to look like when you are done?

Comment: try adding from_dict    :    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(api_r["Data"])

Comment: could you solve your problem?